# Extracting string separately from Excel

Tags: excel

I have rows in Excel in which there is

```
[test].[test1]
```

How can I extract `test` and `test1` separately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the the string is in `A1`, then paste this formula to `B1`:

```
=TRIM(MID(REPT(" ", 999)&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1, "[", REPT(" ", 999)), "]", REPT(" ", 999)), COLUMN(A:A)*1999, 999))
```

You can copy the formula in `B1` to `C1`, `D1`, `E1`,... to get 2nd, 3rd,... word.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the range of cells in a column on which you want to perform the split action. Click 'Data'. From 'Data Tools', Click 'Convert Text to Table'. Click 'Next'. Select the appropriate delimiter check box. Click 'Next'. From 'Column data format', select appropriate option. Click 'Finish'.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use text to columns (as mentioned by pnuts) but here's a couple of other options to explore:

---

VBA:

```
 x = Split(Range("A1"), ".")
  Debug.Print x(0) '// Prints "test"
  Debug.Print x(1) '// Prints "test1"
```

---

Formula:
**=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(".",A1)-1)** *Will return "test"*
**=MID(A1,SEARCH(".",A1)+1,LEN(A1))** *Will return "test1"*

---