# How to extract specific string from a text in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of strings:

```
Building_Level_SpecificNumber Name

B_01_16 Wachschutz
```

and need to extract each part. Here I need = 16. Here is code I manage to get:

1. Building:  `=IF(C10>0,LEFT(C10,FIND("_",C10)-1),0)`
2. Level: `=IF(C10>0,LEFT(MID(C10,FIND("_",C10)+1,256),FIND("_",MID(C10,FIND("_",C10)+1,256))-1),0)`

> 3. Specific number: - not solved yet

4. Name: `=RIGHT(C10,LEN(C10)-SEARCH(" ",C10))`

[see question on attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1KCi.png)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582624/extracting-string-separately-from-excel), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19772389/680068) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31615838/680068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number is always two digits you can use this simple formula looking for the second underscore:

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH("_", A1, SEARCH("_", A1) + 1) + 1, 2)
```

Otherwise you need to look for the distance between the first space and the second underscore as well:

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH("_", A1, SEARCH("_", A1) + 1) + 1, SEARCH(" ", A1) - SEARCH("_", A1, SEARCH("_", A1) + 1) - 1)
```